# Why does iodine get oxidized to iodic acid and not periodic acid by nitric acid?

Tags: redox, oxidation-state

Nitric acid oxidizes iodine to iodic acid, $\ce{HIO3}$ and not periodic acid, $\ce{HIO4}$, which is of a higher oxidation state. This happens although other nonmetals are oxidized to their highest oxidation state. How can this be explained?

Comment: Can u pls give a balanced chemical equation for the reaction of I2 with conc HNO3.

Comment: @Yashwini Sorry. This was a long time back. I am majoring in a completely different field for more than three years

Answer (score 4):

Nitric acid is not strongly oxidizing enough to get iodine to +7.  Relativistic effects tend to make the $s$ subshell valence electrons more stable than the others in heavy atoms<sup>1</sup>. So to some extent, iodine acts as if it has only five valence electrons. To pull out those last two electrons and get periodic acid, electrochemical oxidation is commonly used with a very high oxidation potential.

**References**

1. Relativistic Effects in Chemistry: More Common Than You Thought,
   Pekka Pyykkö, Annual Review of Physical Chemistry **2012** 63:1, 45-64 ([link](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-physchem-032511-143755))
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_acid

Comment: The equation is : $\ce{3 I2 + 10 HNO3 -> 6 HIO3 + 10 NO + 2 H2O}$

Comment: Nitric acid isn't strong enough, but ozone is, isn't it? Still, it doesn't oxidises it to periodic acid... can you explain why?

Comment: It may be easier to get iodine(VII) by [using an alkaline medium](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/152538/17175).